# Shorting Triac gate to ground doesn't turn it off

Tags: capacitor, triac

In the below circuit, `170` is a Q401E3 Triac: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/240/E2Triac-18233.pdf

The capacitors are ceramic disc.

The Triac is rendered normally conducting when `S1` is open.

When I close `S1` the Triac is still conducting when I don't want it to be.

I'm not sure what is wrong or how to fix it; would appreciate any help. The only thing I can think of that is happening is that the path from Engine Magneto to ground through the `S1` switch is of a lower impedance therefore making the Triac useless in the circuit below. The point of the circuit was that when `S1` closes, it allows the spark plug to ignite.

Edit: circuit based on patent `US5190019` https://www.google.com/patents/US5190019

[image]

Comment: That's not shorted.  There's still a 1k resistor in there, now in parallel with a 470 that's always effective.  So the switch has far less effect than you think it does, based simply on that.

Comment: Also, that looks suspiciously like it was drawn for a patent application.  Did I guess right?  Patents are not required to work; only that no one else has applied for that idea yet.

Comment: Yes, It's from a patent but it was also produced in real life so I can't figure out why I can't get it to work.

Comment: The switch does not turn off the triac, rather it prevents it from turning on.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany In testing it doesn't seem to based on the patent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The off-circuit magneto will be pulsed on and off by the engine points or equivalent. When switch S1 is closed, this will prevent the magneto from firing **the next time the points open**.

This works because the the magnetic field from the last points opening has collapsed, bringing the current through the triac to zero. Now the points open again, raising the voltage on the magneto primary. If switch S1 is open, the gate is fired from this rising voltage and the triac turns on. If S1 is closed, the rising magneto voltage is shorted to ground so the triac will not fire. As a result, there is insufficient current developed in the magneto primary to generate enough voltage on the magneto secondary to fire the spark plugs.

Comment: There is no points in the system, and also the circuit isn't working.

Comment: For aircraft, I should have said "breaker" in the primary field. Same concept. If you have neither, perhaps you could explain your magneto circuit.

Comment: If you are attempting to use this circuit with an electronic ignition, it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the circuit description. S1 represents the "points" in a conventional ignition system, and it's the *opening* of the contacts that initiates a spark.

In any case, a triac cannot be turned off via its gate anyway. The only way to turn it off is to allow or force the current through the main terminals to fall below the device's holding current value.

Comment: No, S1 is not the points, it represents the operator seat switch.

Comment: Whatever. I shouldn't have had to guess about the purpose of the circuit. The second paragraph still holds. If your triac is not turning off, it's because you're passing a DC current through it. Magnetos only generate AC, so you must be trying to do something that's outside the scope of the patent.

Comment: You can look at the patent yourself: https://www.google.com/patents/US5190019

Comment: I couldn't look at it before now. You should edit that link into the question itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have now added the google patent link to the question now.

Comment: Is the patent not correct? Thank you

Comment: I didn't say that. Read everything above carefully. What exactly do you have connected to the "ENGINE MAGNETO" terminal of the circuit?

Comment: Engine magneto is as it normally is, the primary kill wire on the primary winding. http://i.imgur.com/ryZFq6e.jpg. The small gauge wire in the photo..

Comment: So you're saying that the circuit is not allowing the engine to run, even when the switch is closed? Perhaps you're using a triac that is too sensitive to dV/dt on its main terminals.

Comment: Dave, yes exactly that! When the switch is closed, it's supposed to allow the spark to be generated but it's not. Also the datasheet to the Triac and part # I'm using is in the original question.

Comment: The Q401E3 is a rather delicate-looking device in a TO-92 package, rated at 400V and 1A. Are you sure that it has not been damaged (e.g., permanently shorted MT1-MT2)? I would really expect to see a much more robust device in an application like this -- at least something in a TO-220 package (1000V and 4A). But that might not solve a dV/dt issue -- I would try putting a small capacitor (or R-C snubber) in parallel with the triac to see whether that has any effect.

Comment: The voltage on the primary wire is really low, tops out at 4VAC, the short circuit current is about 600mA though. I will test to see if the Triac is fried and try your suggestions.

Comment: The circuit does work, the problem was that MT1 and MT2 were swapped.